# Cannot find variable e.getkeycode

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyevent

I'm a beginning programmer using Java and I'm trying to make a game in which you toss a disc through a moving hoop. The disc has a constant downward force and can be moved upward using the up key; however, before I even added any collision detection I started getting an error saying that java compile couldn't find the variable `e` of `KeyEvent`. I looked everywhere online and I'm sure I've just made a dumb mistake but can somebody take a look at this please.

```java
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Random;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DiscHoopToss extends JPanel{

    int x = 710;
    int y = 150;
    int xm = -3;
    int ym = 1;
    int xr = 2;
    Random rng = new Random();
    int r = rng.nextInt((220-20)+1)+20;

  public DiscHoopToss() {
    KeyListener listener = new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        } 

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) ym = -2;
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) ym = 1;
        }
    };
    setFocusable(true);
  }




  private void moveDisc() {
    x = x + xm;
    y = y + ym;

    if (y == 0) {
    y = 150;
    x = 710;
    }

    if (y == getHeight() - 20) {
    y = 150;
    x = 710;
    }

    if (r + xr < 0) xr = 2;
    if (r + xr >getHeight() - 55) xr = -2; 
    r = r + xr;
  }


  @Override
  public void paint (Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g2d.drawOval(50,r,25,55);

    g2d.fillOval(x, y, 50, 20);
  }
  public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Toss the disc into the hoop!");
    DiscHoopToss game = new DiscHoopToss();
    frame.add(game);    
    frame.setSize(750, 350);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        while(true) {
        game.moveDisc();
        game.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the exact compiler error please?

Comment: Side recommendations: don't override JPanel's `paint(Graphics g)` method but rather override its `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method to take advantage of automatic double buffering and to offer safer painting. Also, consider using a Swing Timer to drive your game loop. Use of `while (true)` and `Thread.sleep(...)` is dangerous with Swing apps unless you know exactly what you're doing and are familiar with how the Swing event thread system works and how not to run afoul of Swing threading rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function calls in Java require parentheses. You need to write

```
e.getKeyCode()
```

not just

```
e.getKeyCode
```